# Can I further simplify this code/expression?

Tags: c++, caching, math, optimization

I'm in a DSP context, which I need to speed-up some operations.

Here's a formula I have and I execute often:

```
unsigned int pos0 = (unsigned int)round((envelope.mLengths[sectionIndex] * mSampleRate) / gBlockSize) * gBlockSize;
unsigned int pos1 = (unsigned int)round((envelope.mLengths[sectionIndex + 1] * mSampleRate) / gBlockSize) * gBlockSize;
unsigned int posFinal = pos1 - pos0;
```

Basically, what I'd like to simplify is this math formula:

```
round((a * b) / c) * c
```

Any way? To faster caching/pipeline...

Comment: Have you measured your program to confirm that the above piece of code is a performance bottleneck?

Comment: If `gBlockSize` is a power of 2 you can do a shift (`>>`) instead of division.

Comment: Seems like you are multiplying by gBlockSize in both cases. Perhaps you could take those two multiplications out and just multiply posFinal. That will save you one multiplication. It's not much, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: Better ask such questions at [SE Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) please. Be sure to meet the policies there.

Comment: *"Any way? To faster caching/pipeline..."* - While I don't know your DSP platform; Today's CPU's are way **more** complex than ever before. I am not an expert there, but today, I doubt if its possible to accurately predict cache and pipelining sequence of your program, with all the *Out of Order Execution* and the likes. The best you could do is to use [cache oblivious algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache-oblivious_algorithm) and make hotspots in your program really cache friendly, just to mention a few of knobs that possibly affects performance

Comment: Your question is missing essential information: what are the data types ?

Answer (score 2):

Your answer would probably be more accurate and faster if you just deducted one raw value from the other, then did the mults / divs on that. e.g:

```
auto posRaw = envelope.mLengths[sectionIndex + 1] - envelope.mLengths[sectionIndex];
auto posFinal = (unsigned int)round(posRaw  * mSampleRate) / gBlockSize) * gBlockSize;
```

You get more rounding errors by rounding earlier, it depends on whether those are deliberate or not. The above code does the subtraction on raw values only, then rounds once at the end. But YMMV since it will give slightly different results depending on the inputs. If slight rounding differences don't matter (as I suspect they don't) then round everything once at the end.

Also, you're dividing by gBlockSize, removing any fraction, then multiplying by gBlocksize and casting to (unsigned int). This is the same as subtracting (val % gBlockSize) from val. You can do that with an integer modulus (%) (and you don't have to worry about negative values which could mess up mod since the unsigned int indicates you're only concerned/dealing with non-negatives anyway). So you could simplify things to this:

```
unsigned int posFinal = (envelope.mLengths[sectionIndex + 1] - envelope.mLengths[sectionIndex]) * mSampleRate;
posFinal -= posFinal % gBlockSize;
```

The above code assumes gBlockSize is int, if not, use fmod(posFinal, gBlockSize ) instead of posFinal % gBlockSize

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that floating-point coefficients are allowed, you can precompute `d:= b / c` and evaluate `round(a * d) * c`, which spares a costly division.

Also, if you have to compute the deltas for all indexes, you should evaluate one value at a time and keep a copy for the next iteration. This would spare close to half of the work.